# pass data from java controller to jquery json

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, controller

I can not display chart correctly.
Anybody can help? I am playing with it couple of hours and still nothing.
url - "/testJson" is called, but chart is not displayed

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testJson", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String json(){
    LOGGER.debug("event trigered");
return "[{\"Task\":\"test\"}, {\"Work\":5}]";

        <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
              console.log('test c log');

          $.getJSON('/testJson', function(json) {

            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(request.getAttribute());
            var options = {
                      title: 'title: ',
                      hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
            };
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
          });  
      }
</script>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

it is working only with static data:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
              ['Work',     11],
              ['Eat',      2],
              ['Commute',  2],
              ['Watch TV', 2],
              ['Sleep',    7]
            ]);
```

I noticed that there is an exception thrown : 
     Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Thank you

UPDATE1:
    console.log(json);

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
Task: "test"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
Work: 5
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
concat: concat()
....
```

I changed it to:

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(json));
```

and I received:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

next try:

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(json);
```

cause:
    Uncaught Error: First row is not an array.

Comment: what should `request.getAttribute()` do?? that doesn't make sense to me, as it would return smth different then `arrayToDataTable` would expect.

Comment: Can you print json in javascript? console.log ??

Comment: request.getAttribute() was nonsence, I updated my question